# Is it possible to repeatedly loop through cache data?

Tags: physics, fire, cache

The animation I’m working on is illuminated by about 20 torches. Currently 1000 frames.

I’d like to use a fire animation, via fluid physics, for the torches, in a efficient way, keeping cache sizes to a minimum.

The technique seems to involve baking and the use of a folder for cached data. However, I don’t really need 1000 frames of torch data. Once a torch is on fire, I want to somehow just use the same 100 frames of cached data repeatedly.

---

Following vklidu below, these steps seem to work:

- First I make the fire animation in say fire.blend. The cache, in my case, is at the same location, in the directory fire-cache.
- The scene where I want to use the fire loop is say use-fire.blend.

In use-fire.blend, from the 3D viewport ...

- Add>Volume>Import Open VDB
- Navigate to fire-cache/data, multi select and import all the vdb files. I ignore the fire-cache/config files, which in my case still have a *.uni extension, as they aren't visible in the import dialog.

Those steps create a fluid_data_0001 item with what I guess to be a puff of smoke icon.

In use-fire.blend, I also append the material 'Smoke Domain Material', used for the fire domain in fire.blend. I set fluid_data_0001 to use that material.

Blender 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [fire loop animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtrV8M9YUsI) ... bake cache as VDB.

[image]

Add Object > Volume > Import VDB.
Under P*roperties > Object Data Properties > OpenVDB File* change *Mode* to **Repeat**

[image]

Comment: seems to work ok but is it correct to multi-select and import all the  fire-cache/data/*.vdb files? After the import, only the first one is listed in the fluid_data_0001 properties.

Comment: Blender works like that :) Same for image sequence ... path contains name of a first file in sequence ... if sequence starts with number 365 a path is ... 0365.vdb ... but yes, at some cases could be more user friendly to mark sequence like ####.vdb to let you know it is sequence, but you can know that from second field "Frames".